# Is there a way to dynamically change the color of an icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an star icon. I want to use this icon in an unknown number of colors.

Sometimes I need a red star, sometimes a purple star.

I could dynamically create images on the server with a web service.

What I'm curious about, is there any way to control the color of this icon without explicitly creating an image for every color I may need ?

Comment: Perhaps you could make an icon with transparency and change the color of the background.

Comment: use a canvas object, or a transparent image and change the background colors.

Answer (score 3):

You should use glyphicons or some other type of icon-based font: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons

Here's an example of icon-based fonts in action: http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? I think this is the best solution... (Assuming the icons have fallback methods, which the website I use does)

Comment: I don't understand why glyphicons are suggested. They are sprites, meaning, you need a new one for each color you want, and can't be done dynamically, and only come in certain colors anyways - all what the OP asked not to be. And glyphicons aren't an icon-based font - they're sprites. Also, icon-based fonts are cool, but it seems there are only a set of specific icons you can use. What if there's a custom icon that is needed?

Comment: So create your own icon font?  Looks simple enough to me:  http://www.intridea.com/blog/2012/4/24/symbol-font.  As long as the icon is a single color, this is the simplest way to get what the OP wants.

Comment: @cimmanon That website doesn't even work. There's so many javascript errors, nothing on the page loads. Not a website I'd trust...

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three ways to do this.

1. Create a sprite sheet with all the different colors you need, and shift offsets to change colors.  This is kinda cheating.
2. Dynamically generate the image using Canvas (ugh!)
3. Use SVG, which will respond to changes to the CSS similar to changing text display by changing the class on the DIV/SPAN

Answer (score 1):

With SVG icons you can do whatever you want :)

Here's an example with the Raphael JS Library:
http://raphaeljs.com/icons/

Comment: The link is broken. (Just a comment not an answer to Michael's question)

Comment: The answer or chrislondon is better

Answer (score 1):

You could generate just 4 star images: 1 black, 1 red, 1 blue and 1 green (maybe 1 white too, if you have a non-white background). Then stack all of them and play with their opacity to obtain the color you want.